# Learning PHP from Ruby on Rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I'm a Ruby on Rails programmer and I'm going to work on some PHP projects for a while. I know it's more common for PHP programmers to switch to Ruby on Rails, but are there good tutorials for the other way around?

So question is, does anyone know of any tutorials or resources that could teach PHP to a Rails programmer? I know this may sound vague, but here are some things I prefer:

**Concise** - As much as possible, I prefer short tutorials, not 600-page books. Not a reference guide to PHP but more of a quick start.

**For Ruby on Rails programmers** - I would prefer the concepts to be discussed and compared with Rails, such as how MVC is handled, how dependencies are added, routing, good practices, etc if possible.

**Real World Examples** - It would be really great if there are some real examples, not just a few snippets showing PHP syntax.

Tutorial videos would be better, I would prefer free tutorials but paid ones are fine as long as they're worth it. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I feel sad for you bro. No one should go from ruby to php. It is just inhuman.

Comment: It'l get downvoted. Nothing wrong with the question, just not appropriate in SO.

Comment: If you have a good grasp of programming concepts in general, looking through the basic language section on the php.net documentation should be pretty productive.

Comment: Rails is a framework. PHP is a programming language. It doesn't have routing, MVC, etc.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I've mixed them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paradigm of translating what you know syntactically about one language into another is almost always a recipe for disaster. You will always be trying to bend PHP to do things the "ruby/rails way" instead of the proper way in PHP.

Instead, clear your mind of everything you know about Ruby/Rails (except for general software engineering principles), grab a book, read some tutorials, and watch some "Learn PHP" videos on YouTube. Approaching it as something completely different and not trying to make an apples to apples comparison, you will find that it becomes a little easier to learn.

In the end http://www.php.net is your greatest resource.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to start with some basic syntax and some basic functions of PHP, you can [Read them here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp). It would hardly take 2 - 3 hours to learn basics. and then you can go on with [This PHP tutorial](http://www.php.net/). Then You can strat with some frameworks viz [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) and [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/)

Comment: Cool, I'll check them out, thanks.